# How to add PHP echo in HTML script tags

Tags: php, html, tags

I would like to insert a PHP echo in my HTML footer.

It works in my *header.inc.php*. Example :

```
    <link href="<?php echo $style; ?>" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
```

In my *footer.inc.php* I would like to change this:

```
    <script src="js/jquery-1.11.0.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

to:

```
    <script src="<?php echo $jquery; ?>" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

But my editor (Coda) highlights the syntax like it isn't valid:

[image: syntax highlighting]

Comment: @user3657855: That doesn't mean it doesn't work, could be a bug in Coda. Are you sure it doesn't work in a live environment?

Answer (score 1):

If your php variables are defined you could use:

```
<link href="<?=$style?>" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
```

and:

```
<script src="<?=$jquery?>" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Comment: you shouldn't close the php call, because you will slow your system down by switching in, and out of php mode.

Answer (score -2):

this should work:

```
<?php include "myscripts.php";?>
```

My scripts.php would look like:

```
<script>
.................................
</script>
```

in the specific statement you do:

```
<?php echo "<script src='" . $jquery . "' type='text/javascript'></script>"; //no closing to continue the php coding
```

pay attention to my quoting change, and do it on a PHP page.

Comment: It is if they want to use php within js to change data.

Comment: it answers the question, if you know how to write a php echo statement.  you create it as a php page, then you write JS on it, then put php where you want to use PHP code.  I'm assuming the asker knows how to use a basic PHP echo, and a javascript statement.